# ¿Cómo acceder a localhost desde cualquier equipo fuera de mi red local?

Tags: redes

He desarrollado un pequeño sistema en php, y base de datos en my sql esta en fase de pruebas (Demo), hay clientes fuera de donde vivo (pequeño pueblo) ellos quieren ver el (Demo) entre ellos esta un vendedor... la idea es poder compartirlo en todo momento pero sin publicarlo ya que no dispongo de algun recurso monetario para hacer esto ya abri el puerto de mi modem (movistar Colombia) pero al ingresar desde un dispositivo fuera de mi red no funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has abierto, has redirigido las entradas del puerto 80 a tu ordenador? ¿cómo se conectan, por IP?

Comment: e abierto llamando a Movistar les di la ip de mi ordenador y el puerto 80, pues la idea es esa por ip

Comment: No sé que habrán hecho los de Movistar con tu petición, porque si lo has explicado como me lo has explicado a mi, no se entiende mucho. Tienes que crear en tu modem, una regla para que las peticiones que le lleguen desd el exterior por el puerto 80, se vayan a tu ordenador (IP) al mismo puerto. Hecho esto, tienes que abrir en tu firewall (deduzco que usas windows y tienes el firewall activo) el puerto 80 para que apache reciba las peticiones. Luego tienes que dar la IP a la gente que tiene que entrar, pero la IP es dinámica, probablemente, así que igual te interesa un servicio tipo no-ip.org.

Comment: basta con que sepas abrir puertos en tu modem para aceptar conexiones entrantes y que sepas la direccion ip de tu ordenador que tienes.
No la que te da el router sino la publica.

para abrir puertos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOXvYENROpc

para saber tu ip
https://www.whatismyip.com/es/

el setup de tu router puede cambiar pero dependera del que tengas... y hay muchos para decirte exactamente cual es el paso a seguir...

Comment: voy a revisar muchisimas gracias !!!